# Fix UI of the Reputation Tab Rows

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

This is a bug report originating from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269031/what-do-these-numbers-mean/269047?noredirect=1#comment80678_269047)

In the reputation tab, When a user hovers over a row of his rep:

[image]

the cursor changes to a **pointer**. The problem around the pointer is that The table-row  has the class expandable-row which actually sets the cursor to pointer. But only the post body is actually expandable. Therefore, clicking on the row does not work. You need to click on the post body (or the arrow to the left of it).

Either the row should be made expandable by clicking anywhere on it, or the cursor should not change to pointer on hovering over the row, instead it should do so only on hovering over the rep-body cell.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented in build 3759 on MSE/MSO, and build 2880 on other sites. All expandable rows in the user profile will be clickable anywhere on the row.